# Unable to execute JPA schema generation create command

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, jpa, jdbc

I have a JPA application using Hibernate over JDBC and MySQL, without any application server.

In my persistence.xml I have defined the rules to create, load and drop the database from the scripts:

```
<property name="javax.persistence.schema-generation.database.action" value="drop-and-create"/>
<property name="javax.persistence.schema-generation.create-source" value="script"/>
<property name="javax.persistence.schema-generation.create-script-source" value="META-INF/scripts/create.sql" />
<property name="javax.persistence.sql-load-script-source" value="META-INF/scripts/load.sql" />
<property name="javax.persistence.schema-generation.drop-source" value="script" />
<property name="javax.persistence.schema-generation.drop-script-source" value="META-INF/scripts/drop.sql" />
```

However, when the Maven test goal executes, I get the following error:

**Unable to execute JPA schema generation create command [CREATE TABLE country (]**

The stacktrace looks something like that:

```
Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 1
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:422)
at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:404)
at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.getInstance(Util.java:387)
at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:941)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3870)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3806)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:2470)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2617)
at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2546)
at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2504)
at com.mysql.jdbc.StatementImpl.executeInternal(StatementImpl.java:840)
at com.mysql.jdbc.StatementImpl.execute(StatementImpl.java:740)
at org.hibernate.jpa.internal.schemagen.GenerationTargetToDatabase.acceptCreateCommands(GenerationTargetToDatabase.java:44)
... 34 more
```

The load script starts with creating the country table:

```
DROP DATABASE IF EXISTS bookstore;

CREATE DATABASE bookstore;

USE bookstore;

CREATE TABLE country (
    id          INT(10) UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL,
    name        VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    code        VARCHAR(2) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
    description VARCHAR(1000),
    KEY (id)
);
ALTER TABLE country ADD CONSTRAINT pk_country_id PRIMARY KEY (id);
```

The Country class is mapped in the persistence.xml file and its source code is the following.

```
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table(name = "country")
public class Country extends ro.pub.cs.aipi.lab02.entities.Entity {

    protected Long id;
    protected String name;
    protected String code;
    protected String description;

    public Country() {
    }

    public Country(String name, String code, String description) {
        this.name = name;
        this.code = code;
        this.description = description;
    }

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "id")
    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    @Column(name = "name")
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    @Column(name = "code")
    public String getCode() {
        return code;
    }

    public void setCode(String code) {
        this.code = code;
    }   

    @Column(name = "description")
    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }

    public void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }
}
```

The Hibernate properties in the persistence.xml file are the following:

```
     <property name="hibernate.connection.pool_size" value="1"/>
     <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect"/>
     <property name="hibernate.format_sql" value="true" />
     <property name="hibernate.temp.use_jdbc_metadata_defaults" value="false"/>
     <property name="hibernate.id.new_generator_mappings" value="false"/>
     <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="true"/>
```

I've tried changing the hibernate.dialect to org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect and also to remove the @Table annotation from the Entity class, but I did not notice any change in the behavior.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've managed to figure it out eventually. It seems that hibernate expects only one statement per line and because in my case the script was formatted, it took only the first line of a statement which was thus incomplete.

Reformatting the script and putting a command on a single line solved the problem.

Comment: suggest you report that as a bug in hibernate because other JPA implementations handle such scripts continuations fine

Answer (score 2):

If your JPA providaer is hibernate you can use the following property in persistence.xml to allow multi-line statements:

```xml
<property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.import_files_sql_extractor" value="org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.MultipleLinesSqlCommandExtractor" />
```

Comment: srsly?! I cannot believe this is not a default behavior. And i cannot believe how much time it wasted me. srsly...

Comment: Couldn’t agree more

Answer (score -1):

try to set the value last property choosing one of the following "create", "update", "create-drop", validate.

Comment: `javax.persistence.schema-generation.database.action` has nothing to do with the problem..